# Error in select box getting params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I created a search using 2 select box using 2 conditions

- A select box for ejecutives
- A select box for state of my ejecutive

My error is not getting values when select STATE= 0

But when i select STATE =1 is working

My tables

```
 TABLE EJECUTIVES
       |id|  |name| |lastname1|
 TABLE POLICIES
       |id|  |num_police|  |ejecutive_id| |state|

  state=  '0' is ok
          '1' is canceled
          '2' is expired
```

Here is my controller

```
class PolicyManagement::PolicyController < ApplicationController

   def generate_print_ejecutive_comercial

     @ejecutives = Ejecutive.find(:all)
     @selected_ejecutive = Ejecutive.find_by_id(params[:search])  if params[:search]
     @selected_state = Policy.find_by_state(params[:state])  if params[:state]
     @search = Policy.find(:all,:conditions =>['ejecutive_id = ? AND state = ? ', @selected_ejecutive, @selected_state  ]   )
     @policies = @search.paginate( :page => params[:page], :per_page =>10)

   end

end
```

My models

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
   unloadable
   belongs_to :ejecutive
   has_many :policy
end

class Ejecutive < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :policies
end
```

This is my view but dont know much about it

```
 <% form_tag :controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial" do %>

 Ejecutives: 
<%= select_tag "search",options_for_select(@ejecutives.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s+" "+t.lastname1.to_s,t.id]}, params[:search].to_i ) %>

Status:
<%= select_tag "state", options_for_select([ ["Ok",0],["Cancel",1],["ok but not cancel",2]],params[:state].to_i) %>

<%= submit_tag "search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>

Results
<% @policies.each do |policy| %>
     <p> <%= policy.num_policy%> </p>
     <p> <%= policy.ejecutive.name %> </p>
     <p> <%= policy.ejecutive.last_name %> </p>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @policies %>
```

I tried this but is only getting state canceled(1) ,this is actually working

```
<%= select_tag "state", options_for_select([ ["Ok",0],["Cancel",1],["ok but not cancel",2]],params[:state].to_i) %>
```

Is working only When i select an ejecutive and state "1" = canceled is showing this

```
  Ejecutive Load (0.2ms)  SELECT * FROM `ejecutives` 
  Ejecutive Columns (1.7ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `ejecutives`
  Ejecutive Load (0.6ms)   SELECT * FROM `ejecutives` WHERE (`ejecutives`.`id` = '5') LIMIT 1
  Policy Columns (2.8ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `policies`
  Policy Load (0.7ms)   SELECT * FROM `policies` WHERE (`policies`.`state` = '1') LIMIT 1
  Policy Load (29.9ms)   SELECT * FROM `policies` WHERE (ejecutive_id = 5 AND state = 1 )
```

But when i select an ejecutive and state ok(0),this is not working and showing this

```
  Ejecutive Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `ejecutives` 
  Ejecutive Columns (1.5ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `ejecutives`
  Ejecutive Load (0.1ms)   SELECT * FROM `ejecutives` WHERE (`ejecutives`.`id` = '5') LIMIT 1
  Policy Columns (1.1ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `policies`
  Policy Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `policies` WHERE (`policies`.`state` = '0') LIMIT 1
  Policy Load (8.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `policies` WHERE (ejecutive_id = 5 AND state = 4 )
```

i don't have idea why is doing: SELECT * FROM `policies` WHERE (ejecutive_id = 5 AND state = 4 ) when i selected state ok(0)

And when i select an ejecutive and state expired(2),this is not working and showing this

```
  Ejecutive Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `ejecutives` 
  Ejecutive Columns (1.5ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `ejecutives`
  Ejecutive Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `ejecutives` WHERE (`ejecutives`.`id` = '5') LIMIT 1
  Policy Columns (2.8ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `policies`
  Policy Load (6.4ms)   SELECT * FROM `policies` WHERE (`policies`.`state` = '2') LIMIT 1
  Policy Load (6.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `policies` WHERE (ejecutive_id = 5 AND state = 1098 )
```

i don't have idea why is doing: SELECT * FROM `policies` WHERE (ejecutive_id = 5 AND state = 1098 ) when i selected state expired(2)

I will really appreciate all kind of help

Comment: You tagged your question with the Rails 3.2 and the Rails 3.1 tags at the same time. Which of those are you actually using?

Comment: Where have you logged all values used in your controller?  Why didn't you post those results?

Comment: sorry i'm using rails 2.3

Comment: @7stud do you know why i'm only getting values from state =1 and why is not working with state =0 or 2

Comment: can you post the logs from server when you select state = 0 and state = 1... the logs should show what params are being passed to controller when you submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you make a mistake in your logic and `state = 1` just because Policy with `id == 1` have `state = 1`

Take a look at this:

```
Policy Load (6.4ms) SELECT * FROM `policies` WHERE (`policies`.`state` = '2') LIMIT 1
Policy Load (6.8ms) SELECT * FROM `policies` WHERE (ejecutive_id = 5 AND state = 1098 )
```

In the second query you are searching for policies with `state = 1098` because you are passing the value of `@selected_state`, a `policy` model instance.

Try changing your line to:

```
 @search = Policy.find(:all,:conditions =>['ejecutive_id = ? AND state = ? ', @selected_ejecutive, params[:state]  ])
```